# Best practice for parameters in asynchronous APIs in Java

Tags: java, asynchronous-programming

Is there a best practice for using Guava's `ListenableFuture` in parameters in API calls? Compare these two versions of an interface that internally does a compare-and-set (I'm using Guava's `ListenableFuture`):

```
interface MyDao {
    ListenableFuture<Data> getData(String id);
    ListenableFuture<Boolean> updateData(ListenableFuture<Data> data, int newFieldValue);
}
```

```
interface MyDao {
    ListenableFuture<Data> getData(String id);
    ListenableFuture<Boolean> updateData(Data data, int newFieldValue);
}
```

The first looks a bit messy, and the implementation will likely involve a `Futures.transform` of its own, but you could also argue that it's an asynchronous API, so taking futures as parameters might make sense. Where it gets nice is that it tidies up the business logic when using the interface so it reads like synchronous code:

```
ListenableFuture<Data> data = dao.getData("123");
ListenableFuture<Boolean> success = dao.updateData(data, 10);
```

Compare that to

```
ListenableFuture<Data> data = dao.getData("123");
ListenableFuture<Boolean> success = Futures.transform(data, (Data d) -> dao.updateData(d, 10));
```

And that's with a lambda. It's hideous in Java 7.

The obvious drawback is the interface looks inconsistent. Why is `data` a future, but `newFieldValue` isn't? Should `id` be a future, too? Along those lines, it makes a trivial call incredibly complicated—almost like Java wrapper objects before autoboxing.

It also doesn't do anything to clean up hideous stack traces when futures fail; they still cascade through every `transform`.

Comment: Rather than expecting the user to compose the two futures why not have a single blind `modifyData` method with parameters of `String id, Function[Data => Data]`

Answer (score 1):

I think having a `ListenableFuture` in an API signature method doesn't make it inconsistent.

It's only there to declare **explicity** to the user an asynchronous computation while **hiding** the boilerplate thread logic. *Like an `Optional` would declare **explicity** to the user a possibility of missing data while **hiding** the boilerplate "if not null" logic.*

These 2 links explain a bit more my thoughts: [Monadic Java](http://fr.slideshare.net/mariofusco/monadic-java?next_slideshow=1) and [Use of optional](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained#optional)

However, if you think any user of your API potentially want to call `updateData` but have only an instance of `Data` you could consider adding the corresponding method to your API.

```
public interface MyDao {
    ListenableFuture<Boolean> updateData(ListenableFuture<Data> data, int newFieldValue);
    ListenableFuture<Data> getData(String id);
    default ListenableFuture<Boolean> updateData(Data data, int newFieldValue) {
        //TODO: wrap data in a ListenableFuture and call updateData
    }
}
```